# conversion RGB to CMYK

Tags: image, matlab, icc

I have this question to convert from RGB color to CMYK color.
When I execute the Code I get this result:

```
 ans =
     'RGB'
```

This means that no conversion occurred and the image did not appear to me, what can I do?

```
     folder = iccroot;
     disp(folder)
     profiles = iccfind(folder)
     size(profiles)
     currentProfile = profiles{1}
     currentProfile.Description
     ProfileName = currentProfile.Description.String
     [~,descriptions] = iccfind(folder)
     descriptions
     [profiles,descriptions] = iccfind(folder,'rgb')
     descriptions
     currentProfile.Description
     P = iccread('sRGB.icm');
     P_new = iccwrite(P,'my_profile.icm');
     I_rgb = imread('Pepper.png');
     inprof = iccread('sRGB.icm');
     outprof = iccread('EV2456 User 5000K G2.2.icc');
     C = makecform('icc',inprof,outprof)
     I_cmyk = applycform(I_rgb,C);
     imwrite(I_cmyk,'pep_cmyk.tif','tif')
     info = imfinfo('pep_cmyk.tif');
     info.PhotometricInterpretation
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and found out that the file ''EV2456 User 5000K G2.2.icc' needs
to be in your system. In mine it is missing as I do not have the same monitor as
yours. Check under path

"C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\color"

and if you do
not have the icc file at the ICC Database

https://www.tftcentral.co.uk/articles/icc_profiles.htm

They seems to have two files related to your monitor try either

```
outprof = iccread('eizo_ev2455.icc');
outprof = iccread('eizo_ev2450.icc');
```

and it should works. Works on my system ...
See all the characteristics using

```
info = imfinfo('pep_cmyk.tif')
```